# iOS Firebase Remote Config --- Error Domain=com.google.remoteconfig.ErrorDomain Code=8003

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase's Remote Config here on iOS, whether I call `fetchAndActivateWithCompletionHandler` or `fetchWithExpirationDuration` and `activateWithCompletion`, I have encountered such an error:

> Error Domain=com.google.remoteconfig.ErrorDomain Code=8003 "Failed to
> get installations token.

For this problem, has a friend already solved it? Thx!

I call `fetchAndActivateWithCompletionHandler`
or `fetchWithExpirationDuration` and `activateWithCompletion`, but no solve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have already solved it.

Comment: @LuckyLu Can you please share your working solution for this? I am facing the same issue at my end.